# Properly save selected value from tag in database java Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I need to save chosen the mailing option of every profile in Postgres DB. However, when I try to do it, it saves the option and when I reload the page it goes back to default settings. Every time i change only one changes and others go back to default.
As far as I understand it just rewrites all the values every time. How can I fix it? would appreciate any help.

**JSP**

```
 <form class="col-12 ${flexwrap} justify-content-center mb-1 black p-0" action="<c:url value="/mailing/save"/>"
     <c:forEach items="${listOfProfiles}" var="profile">
         <div>
             <p>${profile.getName()}<br/> </p>
             <p>Current setting ${profile.getMailOption()}</p>
         </div>
         <div>
             <select name="${profile.id}" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                 <option id="${profile.id}" value="daily">Daily</option>
                 <option  id="${profile.id}" value="every3days">Every 3 Days</option>
                 <option  id="${profile.id}" value="weekly">Weekly</option>
             </select>
         </div>
         <br/>
     </c:forEach>
 </form>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/mailing")
public class MailingController {

    @GetMapping("")
    public ModelAndView main() {
        CustomUser user = AuthenticationUtil.getCurrentUser();

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("mailing");
        System.out.println(user.getProfiles());

        List<String> options = CollectionFactory.createList();
        options.add("Daily");
        options.add("Every 3 days");
        options.add("Weekly");
        modelAndView.addObject("listOfProfiles", user.getProfiles());
        modelAndView.addObject("optionsList", options);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping("/save")
    public String save(HttpServletRequest request){
        Map map = request.getParameterMap();

        for (Object key: map.keySet()) {
            String keyStr = (String)key;
            String[] value = (String[])map.get(keyStr);
            System.out.println("Key" + (String)key + "   :   " + Arrays.toString(value));
            Profile profile = ProfileDao.findById(key);
            profile.updateMail(value[0]);

        }
        return "redirect:/mailing";
    }
}
```

Changed one

[image]

Changed the other and first goes back to default

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just moved form tag inside forEach loop and it worked!

Comment: Please edit this answer with a working code snippet, and mark it as accepted.